# How would this React code look without React-hooks and with class components rather than functional components?(Button that open an additional window)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just studied React from YouTube lessons, and there all the lessons were built on classes and the usual this.setState, without hooks. How would this React code look without React-hooks and with class components rather than functional components?
The code itself implements button when clicked on which pops up a window

React:

```
const Modal = (props) => {
  const onClick = e => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('close') || !e.target.closest('.modal-content')) {
      props.close();
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="modal" onClick={onClick}>
      <div className="modal-content">
        <span className="close">&times;</span>
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [ opened, setOpened ] = React.useState(false);

  const open = () => setOpened(true);
  const close = () => setOpened(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Modal Example</h2>
      <button onClick={open}>Open Modal</button>
      {opened && <Modal close={close}>hello, world!!</Modal>}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

full code along with index.html and index.css files at the link:

https://jsfiddle.net/zuscf0wo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Modal` component doesn't need any changes, since it doesn't use hooks.

The `App` component would be written like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    opened: false,
  };

  open = () => {
    this.setState({opened: true});
  };

  close = () => {
    this.setState({opened: false});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Modal Example</h2>
        <button onClick={this.open}>Open Modal</button>
        {this.state.opened && <Modal close={this.close}>hello, world!!</Modal>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```